# When using pyinstaller got Error " has no attribute 'reduce_cython"

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to convert my `modeltest.py` file to exe.
While executing it I got

```
AttributeError: type object 'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

I'm using `scipy 1.1.0` and `Cython 0.28.3` after referring to the solution on the Internet.
I've tried updating `Cython` but had no luck.

Any suggestion to solve this or better way to convert `.py` to exe?
I've tried `py2exe` in a new env with python3.5, which is recommended for tensorflow. But after an hour of study, every time I enter `python setup.py py2exe` in cmd it just returns `running py2exe` and no more response.

I tried freezing it with `cx_freeze` to optain more debugging output but there is nothing. Totally empty, no error, no logs, like I just entered nothing.

Complete log from pyinstall below:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmodel.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\datasets\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\datasets\imdb.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\ndimage\__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\ndimage\_ni_docstrings.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tfgpu\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "stringsource", line 104, in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd
AttributeError: type object 'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
[9828] Failed to execute script testmodel
```

---

UPDATE: 
  I changed the version of `Cython` and `pandas` as Mr.J's list :

```
Cython==0.27.3
h5py==2.8.0
Keras==2.2.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.2
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.1
numpy==1.14.5
pandas==0.20.3
PyInstaller==3.3.1
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
pywin32==223
PyYAML==3.13
scipy==1.1.0
six==1.11.0
tensorboard==1.9.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0
UNKNOWN==0.0.0
```

The error `no attribute '__reduce_cython__'` has gone ,
it comes new error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
ImportError: Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmodel.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
ImportError: Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
[8216] Failed to execute script testmodel
```

---

UPDATE : I remove python3.6 on win7, it still not working.

log below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmodel.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
[4840] Failed to execute script testmodel
```

---

UPDATE: 
I found out the problem related to `Anaconda3\envs\<my_envs_name>\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py`
.And it try to execute this file because of this line in my code :`from keras.model import load_model`(if I turn this line to Comment with `#` , Then I can successfully run the `.exe` file )

the fragment in `pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py` below :

(I insert `print(error)` for debug, I think this function cause the problem)

```
from sys import version_info
if version_info >= (2, 7, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        print('Error!') 
        import importlib
        pkg = __name__.rpartition('.')[0]
        mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')).lstrip('.')
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
elif version_info >= (2, 6, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
        except ImportError:
            import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
            return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
        if fp is not None:
            try:
                _mod = imp.lo

ad_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
            finally:
                fp.close()
            return _mod
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
else:
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
del version_info
try:
    _swig_property = property
except NameError:
    pass  # Python < 2.2 doesn't have 'property'.

try:
    import builtins as __builtin__
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__
```

---

UPDATE:
I changed the filename of `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` in the `dist\project_name\` folder ---which generated by pyinstaller to `tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd`.

And It seems went back to the beginning problem:
`AttributeError: type object 'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'`
There's just a little differences between the logs.

log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmodel.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\datasets\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\datasets\imdb.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\ndimage\__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\ndimage\_ni_docstrings.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py", line 175, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\pyinstaller\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "stringsource", line 104, in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd
AttributeError: type object 'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

---

UPDATE:
I had it solved by using latest developement version of pyinstaller.I found these direction when I trying to open new issue at pyinstaller's page on github :

```
If you have problems to get your application running, please first

＊ try the latest development version, using the following command:

shell
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Even so, I still need to add some files to `dist\<porject_name>`folder manully, including ``` Keras``Keras_applications``Keras_preprocessing``tensorflow ``` folders from 
`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages`

and DLL files from 
`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll`

So i'll keep studying to figure out how to package all files into one .exe file.

Comment: which version of tensorflow and scipy is install on your machine, please let us know which os you are  dealing with.

Comment: you must have minnimum version as listed below,
using pandas-0.20.3, cython-0.27.3 and python-3.5.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the `cython` problem has solved,but now I got `ImportError: Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python.`. I checked tensorflow installation page. `Tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0` should be supported by `python 3.5~3.6`.

Comment: I think you have different versions of python installed on your machined. Check with python

Comment: I program the file in a virtual env with `python3.6` and  convert it in another with`python 3.5.5`. Is it the reason cause this problem ?

Comment: By the way I have python3.6 installed on my original system.

Comment: yes you shouldn't have python version running unless you configured it correctly.
keep python 3.6 in anaconda, remove everything else

Comment: I removed `python 3.6` on my system, but it sill not work , new problem is it `can't find The specified module`.But the file does in the path :`site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py`.I have manually copied few folder and files from `ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\<env_name>\Lib\site-packages` like `keras` `tensorflow` `panas` and  `.dll` files from `\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll` to fix some similar problem .

Comment: Basically, you have a problem with locating packages now, this happens when you have to install packages in anacondas environments.  don't copy, you will end up with many more problem. instead of copy please install packages from anacode package manager

Comment: I did install these packages in the virtual env . But the pyinstaller just can't pack all the files indeed. I copied these files manually because I found someone fixed same problem this way.  I have been sufferd by these problems for days.

Comment: do one thing, check on global site-package checbox while configuring python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I'll keep trying to work it out.

Comment: let me know if you need help, i am happy to help you

Comment: i have gone through this problem, all issue appears when we work with anaconda environment, so i removed everything and keep one global enviornment on my mac, which will consist of all the required package and other tool will just share those package among themself.
i got pycharm/spyder/vcode install and none of this tool having any package install in there venv. everything is referred from global python interpreter

Comment: Do you mean to set up enviroment direct, without anaconda ?Due to installation guide in tensorflow document, the first step is install anaconda. I've remove all my virtual enviroments and set anaconda base enviroment to `python3.5.5` `tensorflow-gpu1.9` `cython0.27.3` `pandas0.20.3` `scipy1.1.0` , but still got `'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'`

Comment: I uninstalled the anaconda ,reinstalled python 3.5 and packages as well .Still had no luck.`'scipy.interpolate.interpnd.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'`

Comment: i will check, give me sometime.

Comment: Man I had it solved by using latest developement version of pyinstaller.I found these direction when I trying to open new issue at pyinstaller's page on github :`If you have problems to get your application running, please first

* try the latest development version, using the following command:

shell
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
`

Comment: Thanks for your help bro .I'm so appreciate of that.

Comment: @GreengeneChung 
You should not add solved to the title of the question, in SO you should publish an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for your mention. I'll do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work it out with steps below:

First of all : Use latest developement version of pyinstaller.

```
If you have problems to get your application running, please first

＊ try the latest development version, using the following command:

shell
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Make sure there are no other `python interpreter` that interfere with your system.
And find compatible version of `python pandas cython scipy`.
Rename the file `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` contained in the `dist\<project_name>` folder to `tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` .

Then copy 
`tensorflow` folder from `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages`

and DLL files from  `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll`
 to `dist\<project_name>`